# Bootstrap grid issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting a weird behaviour with the way pull and push work on medium screens.

This is the grid layout that i am trying to reach.

```
   xs        sm           md               lg
 | 1 |   |   1   |    |  1  | 2 |    | 2 |  1  | 3 |
 | 2 |   |       |    |     | 3 |    | 4 |     | 5 |
 | 3 |   | 2 | 3 |    | 4  |  5 |
 | 4 |   | 4 | 5 |   
 | 5 |



 // html 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">--1--</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--2--</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-0 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--3--</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--4--</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-0 col-md-6 col-md-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--5--</div>
</div>
```

Everything is almost good enough but between 1729px and 1771px (lg screen) everything fails, block #4 is on top of block #1 and block #5 is in a new row below where it should be block #4
So I guess that I am doing something wrong and I didnt fully understood how classes push and pull behave.

Some images

Layout lg

No issue
[image: No issue]

When block 2 height grows bootstrap floats mess everything up
[image: Issue]

Comment: Can you supply a demo or at least a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I think the issue comes out because of the heades that I have in the code, some of the moves into 2 lines and this is when this issue happens

Comment: I didnt realized that this weird bahaviour only happens when block heights are not equal and the mess is originated by the floats

Answer (score 0):

Lose `col-lg-pull-6` for block#4. and push block#5 6 columns.

I think this is what you are looking for?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">--1--</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--2--</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-0 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--3--</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-md-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--4--</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0">--5--</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that I understood why this is happening... But I cant see a solution